# Infinite loop in a circular reference with Entity Framework and .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

My question is: why does Entity Framework Core does it automatically load subclasses when using `.Include`? From my understanding I am supposed to specify the `.ThenInclude` but even without it, it loads..

**The details**

I have an unavoidable circular reference and specifically for that reason I avoided lazy loading, so that I could hard specify what should be included.

My data model - I have highlighted the circular reference:

[image: data model]

A user should be able to subscribe to a bunch of categories.

A job should belong to one or more category

**What I want to achieve**

I built an endpoint that takes 3 optional parameters, a userId, JobId and a collection of categories.

I want to return a collection of jobs filtered by the above parameters

My attempt that is causing the infinite loop

```
var user = await UserAccessor.GetAppUser();

var result = DataContext.Jobs
                        .Include(job => job.Customer)
                        .Include(job => job.Categories)
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .AsQueryable();

if (request.JobId != null)
{
    result = result.Where(job => job.Id == request.JobId);
}

if (request.UserEmail != null)
{
    result = result.Where(job => job.Customer.Email == request.UserEmail);
}
        
if (request.Categories != null)
{
    var categories = await CategoryService.ConvertStringToCategories(request.Categories);
    result = result.Where(job => job.Categories.Intersect(categories).Any());
}

return Mapper.Map<List<Job>, List<JobDto>>(await result.ToListAsync());
```

If I put a `result.ToList()` anywhere in the code and look at the actual values it seems it goes into an infinite loop without me specifying the `.ThenInclude()`.

Have a look at the screenshot below, the infinite loop goes as follows

1. Collection of jobs (this is the result variable)
2. Job has a property collection of category (this I included with `.Include(job => job.Categories)`)
3. Category has a property collection of jobs (this should be null as I didn't include it with a `.ThenInclude()` but it is not arrrggg)

[image: infinite loop in result]

Comment: That's a common confusion. EF carries out *relationship fixup*, i.e. it auto-populates navigation properties if it finds belonging entities in the same query/context. You can't stop EF from doing that.

Comment: In addition to @GertArnold's comment. EF has no issues with "circular" references. Some serializers and mappers do. All they have some options or other ways to handle that, so solve the problem there, not at EF / entity model - they are perfectly fine.

Comment: Some remarks for the comments above, although contextually they're probably meaning EF Core - In EF6 a circular `Include()` will cause exception when using `AsNoTracking()`. Some stackoverflow post mentioned that it doesn't occur in EF Core. Still, I guess it's notable that circular references might be issue in older versions of EF.